# Adding Event listeners | Intercetps on method call

Tags: javascript, class, events, proxy, listener

Given an instance of a `class`:

```
class House {
 open(){}
 close(){}
}
```

is possible to add and event listener on the methods call?

Something like:

```
const house = new House();
house.addEventLister("open", ()=>{});
house.addEventLister("close", ()=>{});
```

without affecting the class definition? So, in fact, adding listeners on methods execution of an instance object knowing only the name of the method?

Functions dispatching some events?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is not possible.

Comment: @MonteCristo I have got an instance from a Framework Class that handle some events with specific methods. I'm looking to add callbacks from another framework to this handling. And It should be interesting to know. I've found out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy.

Comment: in your question you're talking about [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).Which is different to extending / method override/overload.

Comment: @MonteCristo yes because I don't know the correct term. I need to "intercept", not extending or overriding via inheritance. Which is the term for this case?

Comment: to "intercept" a method you need to extend the class and then override/overload the methods. That is the only way.